# Не окончен — cлитно или раздельно?

Tags: частица-не

> Приведенный здесь набросок неокончен, и никто не знает, стал бы его
>   публиковать сам автор.

Являются ли слова «приведенный здесь» зависимыми, и написание «неокончен» должно быть cлитно?

Comment: Пож-та, при изменениях в вопросе сообщайте, ЧТО изменили, а то приходится их выискивать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Приведенный здесь набросок не окончен, и никто не знает, стал бы его публиковать сам автор.**

НЕ с краткими причастиями **всегда** пишется раздельно: урок не выучен, работа не сдана, статья не отредактирована.
[**НЕ с причастиями**](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.56)

*Finis librinon finis quaerendi.* – Книга окончена, но **не окончено** исследование.

*Правда, мы не находим здесь связи народности с мировой идеей, но ведь **набросок не окончен**, статья не завершена.*
В. Греков. Судьбы таинственны веленья

Answer (score 2):

Приведенный здесь набросок не окончен, и никто не знает, стал бы его публиковать сам автор.

Не окончен - краткое причастие, только раздельное НЕ.

Набросок (какой?) приведенный здесь - эти зависимые слова относятся к подлежащему, а не к сказуемому, на НЕ не влияют.

Answer (score 1):

Зависимые слова здесь ни при чем, "не окончен" пишется раздельно всегда.

У вас ещё и запятая пропущена.

Answer (score 1):

Это краткое причастие, поэтому написание с **не** *раздельное*. Зависимые слова (здесь их нет) влияют на слитность написания только полных причастий (неоконченный, не оконченный в срок).